# Selecting *specific* element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm new to jQuery and I'd like to add a class to an individual image by hovering over a button - something I thought I knew how to do, turns out I don't.

The problem being I have several `.service` sections, each with their own `.service button`. Therefore, the end result is as expected: when I hover over the button, ALL the `.service-image` are affected. I thought I could resolve this by using `$(this)` or `find()` but I just cant figure it out...

```js
$(".service button").hover(function() {
  $(".service-image").toggleClass("raise");
});
```

```css
.raise {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="service home-service1">
  <div class="service-image">
    <img src="images/phone.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="service-title">
    <h2>Kiosk Renovation</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="service-text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut feugiat quam sit amet vehicula auctor. Aliquam vel orci hendrerit, vestibulum ligula laoreet, faucibus mi.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="outline-on-dark">Explore</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `<button>` element is a sibling of the `.service-image` you're trying to target (i.e. they both share the same `.service` parent), you can use [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/). By specifying the `.service-image` selector in the `siblings()` function, you can be sure to only ever target the `.service-image` inside of the `.service` element.

```js
$('.service button').hover(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.service-image').toggleClass('raise');
});
```

```css
.raise {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="service home-service1">
  <div class="service-image">
    <img src="images/phone.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="service-title">
    <h2>Kiosk Renovation</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="service-text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut feugiat quam sit amet vehicula auctor. Aliquam vel orci hendrerit, vestibulum ligula laoreet, faucibus mi.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="outline-on-dark">Explore</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses! Don't know how I missed this, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('service button').on('hover', function(e){
  $(this).siblings('.service-image').toggleClass('raise');
});
```

Your thinking was right, as both button and *specific* image share the same parent.